# how to format date in lightning components

Tags: lightning, lightninginput

I'm using lightning input of type date in my lighting component. Once the date is selected it is showing date as **Feb 12, 2019 ** But we want the date to be shown as MM/DD/YY. is it possible

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                    <lightning:input type="date" aura:id="fieldId" label="Start Date of Travel"
                                                     name="startDateOfTravel"
                                                     value="{!v.startDateOfTravel}"
                                                     required="true"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

[image: een]

Comment: Could you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/249825/edit) your question and add some code to illustrate the problm?

Comment: Added code and screenshot for clarity

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***ui:inputDate***, you can define your date format in format attribute.

```
<ui:inputDate aura:id="EndDateField" value="" displayDatePicker="true" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
```

Comment: on validating these using aura:id  the program is not responding. could there be any reason.

Comment: What kind of validation are you doing ?

Comment: var allValid = component.find('expdate').reduce(function (validFields, inputCmp) {

Comment: I'm getting this error

Comment: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Action failed: c:DateValidation$controller$doAction [inputCmp.showHelpMessageIfInvalid is not a function]
Failing descriptor: {c:DateValidation$controller$doAction}

Comment: you referring to some component "expdate", you should use Aura:id with find function.

Comment: this is my code

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249984/action-failed-cdatevalidationcontrollerdoaction-inputcmp-showhelpmessageifi